# iOS Swift: extract a common method using type as input params?

Tags: ios, swift, parameters

I've got 3 methods that are very similar in structure, I would like to extract a common method, looking like this:

```
private func navigateToViewController(animated: Bool, viewControllerType: T, viewControllerNibName: String, mode: MenuMode) { ... }
```

however, I don't know how to handle the type parameter, any good suggestions? Thanks!

```
private func navigateToEditorView(animated: Bool) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    if self.editorViewController == nil {
        let editor = EditorViewController(nibName:"EditorViewController", bundle: nil)
        editor.exitCallBack = self.setBackgroundImage
        self.editorViewController = editor
    }

    if let editor = self.editorViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editor, animated: animated)
    }

    self.currentMenuMode = .editor
}

private func navigateToStorageView(animated: Bool) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    if self.storageViewController == nil {
        let storage = StorageViewController(nibName:"StorageViewController", bundle: nil)
        storage.exitCallBack = self.setBackgroundImage
        self.storageViewController = storage
    }

    if let storage = self.storageViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storage, animated: animated)
    }

    self.currentMenuMode = .storage
}

private func navigateToGalleryView(animated: Bool) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    if self.galleryViewController == nil {
        let gallery = GalleryViewController(nibName:"GalleryViewController", bundle: nil)
        gallery.exitCallBack = self.setBackgroundImage
        self.galleryViewController = gallery
    }

    if let gallery = self.galleryViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gallery, animated: animated)
    }

    self.currentMenuMode = .gallery
}
```

Comment: One issue with trying to refactor this code into one common method is the use of the three different `xxxViewController` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using protocol is the best way to handle all of your questions

```
enum MenuMode {
    case editor
    case storage
    case gallery
}

protocol ExitCallBackHandler where Self: UIViewController {
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)? { get set }; // I don't know what it is
    var currentMenuMode: MenuMode { get }
}
```

Interface of each ViewController

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController, ExitCallBackHandler {
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)?
    var currentMenuMode: MenuMode {
        return .editor
    }
    // ...
}

class StorageViewController: UIViewController, ExitCallBackHandler {
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)?
    var currentMenuMode: MenuMode {
        return .storage
    }
    // ...
}

class GalleryViewController: UIViewController, ExitCallBackHandler {
    var currentMenuMode: MenuMode {
        return .gallery
    }
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)?
    // ...
}
```

Finally

```
private func navigateToViewController<T: ExitCallBackHandler>(animated: Bool, viewControllerType: T.Type) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    var vc = T(nibName: String(describing: viewControllerType), bundle: nil)
    vc.exitCallBack = ...
    self.currentMenuMode = vc.currentMenuMode
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: animated)
}
```

Use it like this way:

```
navigateToViewController(animated: true, viewControllerType: StorageViewController.self)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your function just needs to be generic over `T`:

```
func navigateToViewController<T: UIViewController>(viewControllerType: T, nibName: String) {
    let vc = T(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    print(vc)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your controllers conform to protocol `Exitable`

```
protocol Exitable{
    var exitCallBack: (()->Void)? {get set}
}
```

Make your controllers conform to that:

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController, Exitable{
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)?
}
class StorageViewController: UIViewController, Exitable{
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)?
}
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController, Exitable{
    var exitCallBack: (() -> Void)?
}
```

Now make func:

```
 func navigateToViewController<T: UIViewController & Exitable>(viewControllerType: T?, nibName: String, withExitBlock exitBlock: @escaping ()->Void, animated: Bool) {
        var vc = T(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        vc.exitCallBack = exitBlock
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: animated)
  }
```